# Slide div onclick then back again - Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 buttons side by side that when clicked are tagged with an 'active' class & also trigger a CSS slide effect on a below div.

At first hit of the page, button A is already classed as 'active' & slide 1 is open. When you click button B, it is successfully classed 'active' & the slider successfully slides to slide 2 (right to left).

What I can't get right, is how to now reverse the slider if button A is clicked again. I have looked at examples on live websites that feature the exact same thing, but they seem a lot more complicated than what it has to be.

HTML:

```
<div id="get-in-touch" class="row show-for-medium-up">
    <ul class="tab-navigation small-12 columns">
        <li id="say-hello-form">
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                <h4>Want to say hello?</h4>
                <button id="send-message" class="active" rel="tab1">Send us a Message</button>
            </div>
        </li>

        <h4 class="or">OR</h4>

        <li id="start-project-form">
            <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
                <h4>Want to work with us?</h4>
                <button id="kick-start" rel="tab2">Kick Start your Project</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="say-hello-wrapper-outer" >
    <section id="say-hello-wrapper-inner" class="row">
        <section id="say-hello" class="active hide-for-small tab-container">
            <div id="tab1" class="row tab_content">
                <div class="medium-6 columns">
                    <div id="map">
                        <p>We work remotely with clients all over Australia!</p>
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/map.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="form" class="medium-6 columns">
                    <?php gravity_form(2, false, false, false, '', true); ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="tab2" class="row tab_content">
                <div id="form" class="medium-12 columns">
                    <?php gravity_form(3, false, false, false, '', true); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#say-hello-wrapper-outer {
    background: #f5f6fa;
    width: 100%;
}

#say-hello-wrapper-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #f5f6fa;
}

#say-hello {
    width: 2280px;
    height: 2000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: -1140px;
    // margin-left: -1100px;

    -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.6s;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 0.6s;
    transition: margin-left 0.6s;

    #tab1, #tab2 {
        width: 1170px;
        float: left;
    }
}

#say-hello > #form {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

#say-hello.active {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery("ul.tab-navigation li button").click(function() {
    jQuery("ul.tab-navigation li button").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");

    jQuery('#say-hello').removeClass("active", function() {
      jQuery('#say-hello').addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle would be great to debug

Comment: I've added a live link.

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net, or at least post your relevant HTML and CSS with the javascript you posted .. it's really hard to search your site to find the problem :)

Comment: I've added the HTML & CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to run the same thing on each button, you might to differentiate them using an if statement:

```
jQuery("ul.tab-navigation li button").click(function() {
    jQuery("ul.tab-navigation li button").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    if (this.id == "kick-start"))
      jQuery('#say-hello').removeClass("active");
    else
      jQuery('#say-hello').addClass("active");
});
```

That would apply the class "active" to the slider only when you press the kickstart button.

If may I give you a little suggestion not totally related to your question is to start naming things in a less confusing way, for example applying the "active" class to both a slider and a button and playing around with in the same scope function it soon start to be pain when you try to debug it.

Also, try to write the code as it would be writing a standalone package for yourself to reuse it as much as you can without readapting it, which means the following:

- Stop using IDs in both CSS and JS unless is strictly necessary
- Put all the related items under a same container, buttons in one section and the driven slider on another is non-sense.
- Use data-attributes on buttons to pass information, for example data-position="" can tell the number of the slider attached to the button or the direction of the slide.

You probably will agree with me that `<button class="js-slider" data-position="left">` works more efficiently than using and recoding each button element every time.

It might sound obvious for somebody, but this gives you the ability to start writing cleaner and lightweight code which is extremely easy to debug for you (and others to help you).

Comment: Thanks, that makes total sense! To get as far as I had, I had copied the structure from another website, but I agree that it could have been a lot more concise. Thanks for the tips anyway.